# Hosted SVN, what about connectionstrings?

Tags: asp.net, svn, hosting

I'm considering a hosted SVN solution, preferably with Trac, but I have a major concern in doing so: Connectionstrings.

I mainly work on websites, so all of them have a connectionstring in web.config, which means my DB password would be "exposed" to the hosted SVN provider.

What have you guys done/thought about this "security hole" when you choose to use a hosted SVN provider ?

I'm looking for either a way to avoid the connectionstring from being read by the provider, or just some clever insight into why I shouldn't worry :-D

EDIT: To clarify the sites are indeed ASP.Net based.

EDIT #2: Would it perhaps be safer to simply buy a hosted server, and install SVN, Trac and so forth on it myself ? (Like http://www.slicehost.com/)

Comment: @Linus Kleen Come, now, you don't have to remove the asp.net tag I just added, do you?  :)  It is relevant at least to the answer I gave.

Comment: @Andrew Yes. It's relevant to *your* answer. Not to the question.

Comment: @Linus Kleen I disagree.  The question really concerns how to conceal sensitive data, likely in Web.config, from someone who can view a public repository.  Because there are strategies specific to doing this with Web.config that are not relevant to other technologies, ASP.NET would make some sense -- possibly more so than the two tags that currently remain.  I'm not going to retag this, but I'm not sure the "right" expertise would be drawn to this question by its tags right now.

Comment: @Andrew I apologize. You were right, of course. I rolled back my edit to your revision. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting a hosted server instead, this way I control the root password etc. and don't have to worry about others poking around inside my code :-)

Answer (score 3):

If security is a big concern you should host the SVN your self.
Connection strings is only one of many aspects you should worry about. Others are the SVN host or someone hacking the SVN host taking/stealing/selling your entire code base and/or searching for exploitable bugs in the source code. There is even the possibility of modifying your code and injecting back doors into the code.

Either you trust the SVN host or you don't. If you don't trust it, find some one else or host your self.

Comment: +1 You're right there are other and worse matters to worry about as well. Stealing/selling my code is not a major concern for me though (long story short: the sites aren't likely to be useful to anyone but me)

Answer (score 1):

I added the ASP.NET tag, since it's both implicit to your question and relevant to this answer.

Don't post the connection strings themselves.  There are a couple ways you can do that.  One is to svn:ignore Web.config, though this may be undesirable since there are often changes there worth tracking.

If you're using at least the latest MSBuild, or more likely Visual Studio 2010, you can use multiple Web.config files so that you have one per environment.  This helps because you can have a "base" Web.config that does not actually include the connection strings, then use svn:ignore on Web.debug.config and Web.release.config, where you actually will add the connection strings.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698.aspx#webconfig_transformation.

Comment: +1 I do use VS 2010, and already have the connectionstrings in the debug/release parts of my web.config, so this would be an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because these strings are a secity risk, and because they are different for different installations, I tend to provide a configuration **template** in my svn.

Whenever I do a checkout you need to instantiate your template to a real config, or if you feel fancy, run an install script. Make sure your configs do not migrate from an install to your svn, and you're homefree.